# How to get the largest possible rectangle contained inside polygon

Tags: python, c#, polygon, arcgis, rectangles

I am looking for a solution to get the largest possible rectangle inside a polygon.

currently I am using Arcpy for ArcGIS (python library), but there is no out of the box solution for getting it, instead there is a feature named Minimum Bounding Geometry (this returning the opposite result, a rectangle contains the polygon):

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm

Example of the required result:

[image: 1]

Comment: Interesting problem. To be sure: 1. can the polygon be self-intersecting or not? 2. "largest" rectangle refers to the rectangle area? 3. The solution might not be unique, so you are looking for one solution or all of them?

Comment: Did you already google for "polygon largest rectangle"? It will lead you to the discussion of an algorithm which even contains exactly the picture you posted.

Comment: This is not in Python but might help: https://gitlab.com/b-rowlingson/maxrectangle

Comment: @KlausGütter

1- no not self intersecting
2- largest means area right
3- I need optimal solution

Comment: "optimal solution" - but there might be multiple solutions with the same area, think e.g. of the case where the polygon is in fact an octagon - here you get two solutions. Did you already check https://d3plus.org/blog/behind-the-scenes/2014/07/08/largest-rect/?

Answer (score 2):

The best I've found is described in an academic paper titled "Finding the largest area rectangle of arbitrary orientation in a closed contour". Available in PDF, but copyright precludes me from linking the doc, which you can get to via the publisher https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0096300312003207.

The algorithm is O(N^3) and the authors claim there is no other with lower time complexity (which does NOT imply that it is most efficient for all use cases).

(My implementation (C#) was for a client who owns the code, so you will have to roll your own version unless it's been open sourced in the meantime.)